# Double blow detection in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudiorecorder

I have seen many tutorials over internet to detect blow in iPhone but my app's requirement is that I need to detect single blow and double blow both so that if user blow single time it can perform action a and if the user blow two times together then to perform action b.

Any way to do this?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 2):

Surely if you know how to detect a single blow, you could just have a timer with a threshold & see if another blow happens within that time? Something like -

```
-(void)userDidBlow {

    if (hasBlownOnce) {

        hasBlownOnce = NO;
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(singleBlowTimedOut) object:nil];

        // do double-blow stuff

    } else {

        hasBlownOnce = YES;

        [self performSelector:@selector(singleBlowTimedOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:kDoubleBlowTime];

    }

}


-(void)singleBlowTimedOut {

    hasBlownOnce = NO;

    // do single-blow stuff

}
```

I haven't tested it, but it looks ok :)

Comment: I also haven't tested it but it looks ok. :)

Comment: Did you get a chance to try it?

Comment: Not yet because project will be started a few later. I'll keep posted if get any success or failure. :)

Comment: Hi, I also want to achieve same thing but i want to detect blow only once .. can you please tell me how did u achieve detecting blow?

Comment: It won't necessarily work if using AVAudioRecorder to get the microphone input, as there will be a latency before being able to detect the second blow.